Just graduated with a PhD in engineering and discovered that my published dissertation lacks novelty. What could happen next?
I recently graduated from a top engineering school in the US. My dissertation, composed of three related chapters, was approved by my advisor and three committee members during both my preliminary and final examinations. It represents three years of hard work. Each semester, I presented updates to the lab members (6 to 12 people). Prior to graduation, I submitted each chapter for publication. The first two were published in reputable journals before I graduated.
Three months after graduation, I received feedback on the third paper. The feedback was shocking and has caused me significant distress. It appears that the main idea of my second paper, which I considered the crown jewel of my dissertation, was first hinted at in a 2014 publication that I missed during my literature review. Additionally, works published in 2019, 2020, and 2023, which I also overlooked due to their use of nonintuitive keywords to a nonexpert, greatly undermine the novelty of the main idea of my second paper. While my second paper still includes novel aspects like a unique case study, results, unique application, and other considerations, the main idea is not as original as I claimed (" I am the first to creat a model that would do this and that").
What might happen now? Will the journal retract my publication? Will I lose my PhD?
Please advise me on the best course of action to take.

This happens far more often than you may believe. Literature search can be tough. You are in good company. Publications and PhDs are not normally retracted for such reasons.

It is unlikely that anything will happen. Journals are unlikely to retract papers for other than misconduct or fraud. Universities are also unlikely to retract degrees except in extreme cases. If there were failures, then they are shared with many people including your advisor and committee and reviewers and editors of already published papers.
The only consequence that is likely is that things that haven't been published already are unlikely to be.
Don't beat yourself up. Things happen. Things get overlooked. Move on.
You still have opportunities to extend what you did, based on what you learned as you progressed.
Edited to add: I'm assuming of course that no one has accused you of plagiarism. That would be a different matter altogether. But, such a claim would have properly occurred much earlier.

+1. To the OP, these things really do happen. When I was a grad student my coauthor and I discovered - days before submission - that every single result in our joint paper had already been proved by someone else, and there was nothing to salvage. It was pure luck that we discovered this before submitting. Obviously there may be concrete lessons to draw from this (how specifically could you have tweaked your literature search to find these papers?), and I definitely sympathize, but it's really not the end of the world.

You got your PhD because you demonstrated that you can work independently and creatively, on topics that you and everyone around you believed to be new. The journals that published your work also believed that. As a consequence, there is nothing you ought to be concerned about -- congratulations on your PhD and on getting your work published!
